# openpyxl not found in exe file made with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, openpyxl, geopandas

I wrote a Python code using a virtual evn with pip, and I built it with pyinstaller to use it as executable, and it works. Now I'm moving to conda environment to use also geopandas, fiona and gdal. I can run it without any errors, but if I build the code into the .exe, this error raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\workbook\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_write_only.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 23, in init openpyxl.worksheet._writer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl.cell._writer'
[12248] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

I tried also to reinstall openpyxl through conda, but nothing changed.
The command line to build is:

```
pyinstaller --onefile main_new.spec main.py
```

and the spec file is:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('./inputs/*.csv', 'inputs')],
             hiddenimports=[
             'openpyxl',
             'xlrd',
             'xlswriter'
             ],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='DESAT',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure pyinstaller is installed in your conda env and that is the version you are using (eg make sure `where pyinstaller` returns the version in your conda env bin)

Comment: I checked, pyinstaller is in the conda env that I'm using. There is only one version of it, and in the same folder there is the openpyxl folder and the openpyxl-3.0.10-py3.7.egg-info folder (as numpy, pandas, etc folders). It seems all fine here, or not?

Comment: Minor update: the version is the 4.8. Should I downgrade to the 3.7 that is the same of Python used in the conda env?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is referring to 'openpyxl.cell._writer' that is inside openpyxl. in fact, pyinstaller was actually able to find openpyxl.
I checked inside, and I found that in the pip environment i was using the 3.0.9 version, while in the conda one I was using the 3.0.10.
Downgrading to 3.0.9, no --hidden-import or other needed, it is just working.

Answer (score 5):

Explicitly importing the module does the trick. It can be imported from the command line, or by modifying the .spec file to import.

Command line mode:

`pyinstaller main.py --hidden-import openpyxl.cell._writer`

Note: The module name does not need to be wrapped in quotes

Modify the .spec way:

```
a = Analysis(
...
    hiddenimports=['openpyxl.cell._writer'],
...
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks ! was struggling with this issue for last 2-3 months. One modification I added was including the --onefile option so : pyinstaller main.py --hidden-import openpyxl.cell._writer --onefile. It worked perfect. but any difference b/w the exe if that option isn't used?

Comment: Hi user76170: glad to help you. The --onefile option will generated a big exe file that contains everything in it. When running the exe, it will extract  files it contains to a temporary directory and execute. Without the --onefile options will get an exploded directory with a small booting exe file and other  things it needs to run.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help to collect all submodules of openpyxl when building your *.exe.

Refer to this or to the many answers on this platform regarding hook-files:
https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/hooks.html#PyInstaller.utils.hooks.collect_submodules

**edit**: In my case I use it this way:

hook-files in the directory of your *.py (you want to convert) contain the `collect_submodules` function (right side in the screenshot) and in the *.spec file the `hookspath` is defined to be the same as your *.py (left side of the screenshot)
[image]

Comment: Hi, I just had a try using openpyxl in the hidden imports of the 'spec' file, and
'pyinstaller --onefile --collect-submodules=openpyxl main_partial.spec main.py'
but nothing changed. Should I add a specific path somewhere to help pyinstaller finding openpyxl?

Comment: I added some details to my answer, so you better understand what I meant. Regarding your build command: Afaik it is enough to define the *.spec file and not mention the *.py anymore ```pyinstaller --onefile main.spec```